# Add automatic test to package examples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Our package has a few example scripts that show how the package can be used.

Whenever we make a breaking change in my package, the examples may need to be updated. Right now I need to manually keep track of this, by checking whether the example scripts still run. Is there some way to add a test_examples function to my unit testing setup that doesn't assert the return value of a specific function, but simply runs all (or specific) files in the examples folder and checks that these scripts complete without error?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html documentation is not the answer?

Comment: As far as I can see your link only shows the typical use case of asserting that the return of a specific function is as expected - not whether a script that calls several function runs without errors

Comment: Of course you have to cover all functions in your code. Each function in your code should have a bunch of tests for each types of possible mistakes. And this link leads to documentation not to direct article so read deepper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was much easier than I thought it would be. I simply needed to add a test function to my pytest setup that imported the example scripts. Since these scripts aren't protected by a, `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, all content is run. If there are errors along the way, the import, and therefore the test, will fail.